# How can I send a String to a web service using POST request (react native)?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, post

Is it possible to send a String to a PHP web service using a POST request (react native)? I only find some JSON POST requests like the following:

```
functionName = async() => {   
    const response = await fetch('http://localhost/webservice.php', {
      method: 'POST',
      mode: 'no-corse',
      headers: {
        Accept: 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        searchQuery: 'something',
      })
    })
    const myData = await response.json();
    this.setState({data: myData});
  }
```

How can I transform this to send a String (like just one word) instead of a JSON String?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like

```
functionName = async() => {   
    const response = await fetch('http://localhost/webservice.php', {
      method: 'POST',
      mode: 'no-corse',
      headers: {
        Accept: 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'text/plain'
      },
      body: 'Your text'
    })
    const myData = await response.json();
    this.setState({data: myData});
  }
```